# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException - java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException in java

Tags: java, ssl

I'm new one for web site crawling process in java, currently I'm facing the issue `SSLHandshakeException`, while crawling the site's like `http://` based no issues on moving to `https://` having the issues, most wide I've searching the result always being certificate issue, still i didn't get specific solution for it!, please some one give the solution for it. Here my output:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1520)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:182)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:176)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:975)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:123)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:511)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:449)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:817)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1029)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1056)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1040)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:405)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:170)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:133)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:512)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:534)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:493)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:205)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:194)
at jobcrawl.jobcrawl.main(jobcrawl.java:112)
```

Caused by:

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:251)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:234)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:148)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:218)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:209)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:249)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:954)
... 16 more
```

Caused by:

```
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:195)
at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:250)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:246)
```

Comment: install the SSL for the particular site in the server where you try.

Comment: Can you post the code where you try to access the site?

Comment: Your truststore must contains the certificate of the server that you are connecting to.

Comment: @Sajith your truststore must contain an **anchor (cert) for** the server cert; for most certs/chains this is a **root CA**, which can serve as anchor for thousands or millions of servers. You need the actual server cert only if that is self-signed (and thus its own root) which is bad practice to do on the public net (although people do commit bad practice). Putting lots of server certs in your truststore is a good way to establish a routine that leads to you trusting malicious sites that steal your data and/or money etc.